# Having problems with copying code to a drop down menu button to create a second drop down menu button

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm new to HTML/CSS and i'm still learning.

I've just finished creating a drop down menu button, here is the code http://cssdeck.com/labs/he8ykb8n

As you can see the navigation menu only have the "Men's Wear" button with a drop down menu.

I'm trying to copy that code and make a second drop down menu button next to "Men's Wear" button.

The problem is when i copy the code for "Men's Wear" button the second button doesn't align next to the "Men's Wear" button, instead it shows up down below.

This is what I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZtoq.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd menu is breaking, because first menu is acquiring the complete width of header and so there is no space for 2nd menu at top. So you have to manage width of every **li tag**.
Try this class, not yours and see the difference :

```
.menubar { 
   width:200px !important; 
   float:left; 
   list-style: none;
 }
```

Comment: thanks alot @Sushil Kandola, it worked. I would've upvote your post, but unfortunately i dont have enough points yet. Thanks again

Comment: the only problem now is that there is a bit too much space between the two buttons. Is there any way i can move the second button closer to the first button? Appreciate your help

Comment: Not An Issue for Vote-Up. For more space, you can remove(or minimize) width from class menubar, as defining widths is not a good idea. You have to manage child li's at all by defining their width and positions.

Answer (score 0):

I would try aligning the dropdown menus using divs or a table